# How do I read the text in a submitted summernote textarea in asp.net VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, summernote

So I'm going off a template here that is using this markup:

```
<!--Wysiwyg editor : Summernote placeholder-->
<div id="demo-mail-compose"></div>
```

With this script:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
if ($('#demo-mail-compose').length) {
    $('#demo-mail-compose').summernote({
        height: 500,
        toolbar: [
                   ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'clear']],
                   ['insert', ['link']],
        ]
    });
....
```

Upon a button submit, I'm not sure how to collect the value of the summernote textarea server side since it is generated on the client....

Comment: is this a webform or mvc or will you be talking to a webservice?

Comment: Add a ASP Hidden Field control to the page and assign the value from the dynamically created Summernote textarea using the onChange event (which is apparently a thing) - see https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/348. Then when the page posts back, you just get the value from the hidden field.

Comment: Please go though this link to get solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/29562552

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I would use the onChange event as Adaam mentioned because of the last note on his link that says "onChange does not seem to fire when buttons are selected such as center align or changing a font".

I would add a hidden field control and fill this field when the submit button is clicked by using the OnClientClick event of the button.  See example below:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdfSummernoteValue" />

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Save" OnClientClick="getSummernoteValue();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSummernoteValue() {
        $("#<%= hdfSummernoteValue.ClientID %>").val($('#summernote').summernote('code'));
    }
</script>
```