# Summernote and form submission in MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, summernote

I am using the summernote plugin for text box:
http://summernote.org/#/getting-started#basic-api

This is the form I have using summmernote:

```
<div class="modal-body" style="max-height: 600px">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
            <div id="textForLabelLanguage"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn " })
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#textForLabelLanguage').summernote();
    });
</script>
```

Now, In my controller, this is the code I have:

```
public ActionResult Create(UserInfo newInfo , [Bind(Prefix = "textForLabelLanguage")] string textForLabelLanguage)
{
    //logic here
}
```

Now the problem is that `textForLabelLanguage` param is always null.

This happens because I have to pass `$('#textForLabelLanguage').code();` into MVC when submiting the form but I have no idea how to do that!

How do I solve my problem?

Comment: where is your form element that will have the html?

Comment: It is right before the javascript. That is teh HTML using mvc forms generation.

Comment: I mean the input field?

Comment: @DanielA.White: ` <div id="textForLabelLanguage"></div>`. This is it. And then the JS does the rest. It is all in the summernote documentation :D

Comment: That isn't an input field

Comment: @DanielA.White: I never said it was :P Tricky isn't it? You just assumed it !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found my solution to the problem. This is how I am making the controller get the correct information:

```
<div class="modal-body" style="max-height: 600px">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
            <textarea name="textForLabelLanguage" id="textForLabelLanguage" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn " })
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#textForLabelLanguage').summernote();
    });
</script>
```

Basically, if I use a textarea with a name instead of an input or anything else, it works!

However, and be warned, even though this solution works, I then get a error in the controller saying:

**A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client**

This happens because I am allowing HTML. But this is a problem for another question!

Comment: FYI `[ValidateInput(false)]` allows HTML to passed to a controller action

Answer (score 8):

Please, use `[AllowHTML]`

There's a good article on MSDN
**[Request Validation in ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339.aspx)**

"To disable request validation for a specific property, mark the property definition with the AllowHtml attribute:"

```
[AllowHtml]
public string Prop1 { get;  set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

similar to what was posted earlier you can use the HTML helper

```
@HTML.TextAreaFor( m=> m.text, new {@id = "textFor*Model*"})
```

instead of `<textarea>`